# Capybara: Find element with unknown tag

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I want to find an element that has a ng-model attribute with Capybara. I dont know the tag of the element, how can I still search for the element?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the html .

Comment: Not neccessary. I want to find an element with an ng-model attribute. I want to know if it is possible to find it just with that information, or if more is needed

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, if anyone is interested:

```
find(:css, "input[ng-model]")
```

works also without using a tag:

```
find(:css, "[ng-model]")
```

Sometimes its really just simple.